# const integer simple

Tags: c++, constants

I am trying to go through [C++ Intro](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/assignments/MIT6_096IAP11_assn01.pdf)

It's written there "• const int i = 3 // can’t change the value of const variable"

but my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

 int main()
{

const int i = 44;//trying 
cout<<i;
return 0;
}
```

Works 
      Why ?
         Also I use codeblocks In Windows 7

Comment: Would be pretty worthless to have it at all if `const` meant that you couldn't even assign an *initial* value to a symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You never change the value of `i`, right?

```
const int i = 44; // initialization - OK

i = 44; // assignment - not OK
```

Answer (score 1):

statement `const int i = 3` tells the c++ compiler that `i` is a variable of type int which is a constant and has the value 3.

This means any further attempt to change the value of i will lead to compilation errors. in your sample code you cant change the value of i after the first initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `i` is declared as `const`, which means that it can only be initialized, but cannot be changed later in code. It would, however, not make sense if all constants would have to have the value `3`, don't you agree? So when initializing, you can set it to any integer value you like; but the compiler won't allow you to change it later in your code; try this, it will give you a compiler error:

```
const int i = 3;
// ...
i = 44;   // <- here the compiler will complain, saying that i was declared const
```

Answer (score 0):

const means once set, you cannot change the value of that variable during the execution. But, the value can be set to anything the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It works because you have not changed the value of "i" in your code

```
const int i = 44; // Initialization of a const value, OK.

cout << i; // Just reading the value, this is OK

i = 44; // This will not work because you can't change the value of a const type.
```

Answer (score 0):

It works because there's a difference in C++ between *initialization* and *assignment*.

When you declare a variable, you can choose to initialize it:

```
int i; // i is uninitialized
int j = 42; // j is initialized
```

after this point, once the variable *exists*, you can no longer initialize it. It has whatever value it has now (`i` has some random garbage value, and `j` has the value `42`). All you can do instead is *assign* a new value to it:

```
i = 43;
j = 44;
```

When a variable is const, you can't *assign* a new value to it. You can still *initialize* it, but once it has been initialized, it can never change.

So `const int i = 44` is perfectly valid, because you are *initializing* a new variable, rather than *assigning* a new value to an existing variable.